# Reset localstorage variable at specific time

Tags: javascript, datetime, local-storage

How do I reset a `localStorage` variable that is a `boolean` that tracks whether a user has completed an action that day. When the time reaches, for example, `8 am local time`, it resets the `boolean` to `false` to show that the action hasn't been completed yet.

If the user has completed the action that day, the `localStorage` variable gets set to `true` and we show the countdown to `8 am`.

Here are my methods that check for current time and time until `8 am`.

```js
const setActionCompleted = () => {
    var hasCompleted = true;
    localStorage.setItem("action-completed-today", JSON.stringify(hasCompleted));
}

const twoDigits = (number) => {
    return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
}

const countDown = () => {
    var reset = new Date();
    var now = new Date();
    reset.setHours(8, 0, 0);
    if(now > reset){
        reset.setDate(reset.getDate() + 1);
    }

    var timeToReset = ((reset - now) / 1000);

    var hours = ~~(timeToReset / 60 / 60) % 60;
    var minutes = ~~(timeToReset / 60) % 60;
    var seconds = ~~timeToReset % 60;

    return `${twoDigits(hours)}:${twoDigits(minutes)}:${twoDigits(seconds)}`;
}

const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(countDown());
}, 1000);

// clear interval after 10 seconds so its not running indefinitely
setTimeout(() => {clearInterval(intervalId)}, 10000);
```

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are initially setting up the localStorage entry?

Comment: Why not just store when the action was last completed then check if that meets whatever criterion is required at the time it's actually needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple different options here. You could expire the item periodically, and then do `localStorage.removeItem()`, then check your boolean on if `localStorage.getItem()` finds an item matching your criteria instead of changing the associated value to `false`. To do so, you'll want to create a custom wrapper around `localStorage.setItem` so that it can accept a third prop for the expiry time like:

```
function setWithExpiry(key, value, interval) {
  const now = new Date();
  const item = {
    value: value,
    expiry: now.getTime() + interval,
  };
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
};
```

Then when you get items from localStorage, if the current time is past the item's expiry time, have it remove item by key from localStorage and return null.

```
function getWithExpiry(key) {
  const itemStr = localStorage.getItem(key)
  if(!itemStr) {
    return null;
  }
  const item = JSON.parse(itemStr);
  const now = new Date();
  if (now.getTime() > item.expiry) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    return null;
  }
  return item.value;
}
```

Theoretically then you could just reset the value to `false` when it's found if it is expired instead of removing it though, if you want.

Comment: So `getWithExpiry` could be checked on component mount or would that make since to check inside the `countDown` method if the expiry has passed?

Comment: I'd check it on component mount, personally. You can also place it within a useEffect hook to get more control over when it re-checks.

Comment: I am thinking that will be enough, because if the action was completed today it would really only need to check when ever they come back to the component. Will implement and get back to ya!